# Integration of $\sin(x)/x$ from $0$ to $1$: exact value

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I am trying to find the area under the curve $\sin(x)/x$ between $x=0$ and $x=1$, i.e. $\int_0^1\sin(x)/x$.

By the Taylor's series approximation (and proper justification), the answer gets to be
$$
1-\frac{1}{3\cdot 3!} + \frac{1}{5\cdot 5!} -\frac{1}{7\cdot 7!}+\cdots
$$
The values of first three partial sums of the above series go near to $0.94$.

If I want to know the exact limit of the above series, can one suggest some way?

Comment: What is Si here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\sin (x)}{x} \, dx=\text{Si}(1)\approx 0.946$$ where $\text{Si}$ is Sine integral, a special function  defined by $\text{Si}(x)=\int_0^x\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt$

---

**edit**

Since
$$\text{Si}(1)=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1) (2 n+1)!}$$
is an alternating series, taking the first four terms gives about $0.946083$ with a maximum error  given by the first term we neglet in absolute value, that is $3\times 10^{-7}$ which means that $6$ decimal digits are exact.

TL;DR

The integral has no solution in terms of known function, so mathematicians defined a special function to name this result. There are many others, like  Cosine integral
$$\text{Ci}(x)=-\int_x^{\infty}\frac{\cos t}{t}\,dt$$